# Rails update record through Ajax with select_tag and onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have an index view displaying a table data that I'd like to be able to update through a select_tag onchange dynamically within view vs. needing to submit a form and rendering the page again. Would this be a Coffeescript function to detect an onchange that captures the new value and submits it to a controller action for updating? With multiple select_tags, how should they be ID'd uniquely and how does the coffeescript function differentiate? Thank you.

Currently, each table row is simply displaying the dropdown with options and setting the current value. I'd like this to update the record immediately upon change. Presumably these will each need their own select id to differentiate?

```html
<td><%= select_tag(:domain_type_id, options_for_select(@domain_types, d.domain_type_id)) %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up discovering the [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem as a solution for quickly rendering select boxes for editing multiple records "in place".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check [smart_listing](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing) gem, check the Cart support example, this gem can help you to get line editing and some ajax actions without pain. Hope it helps.